# Knockout.js Calling API from View Model

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am calling the Foursquare API from the View Model of Knockout.
I get no errors, but I see in the network tab no sign of the API getting called.

Do I need to add specific code to call the API in the View Model?

```
var ViewModel = function(){  
console.log("View Model started")

var self = this;
// Foursquare API Call : 

self.venueList = ko.observableArray([

    ]); 

this.foursquareURL = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=37.8,-122.4&query=croissant&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET';


 this.fs_ApiCall = function()
 {
    console.log("API called");

$.getJSON(foursquareURL, function(data){

    //Add a header
$foursquareElem.text('Croissants');


var venues = data.response.venues;
self.venueList = ko.observableArray([]);

    for (var i=0; i<venues.length; i++){

          console.log(venues[i].name);
    self.venueList.push ({

            name: venues[i].name,
            lat: venues[i].location.lat,
            lng: venues[i].location.lng 



    });   

 console.log(self.venueList()[i].name)
    } 

    }).error(function() {
$foursquareElem.text( "No data available" );
});
};

};




ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foursquare-venues"> 

 <ul data-bind= "foreach:venueList">
<li id="li-name" data-bind = "text: $data.name">

</li>
```

Comment: Is the `foursquareURL` of your `getJSON` call an outside variable? Otherwise, you might want to get your `this.foursquareURL`.

Comment: All needed paramenters (IDs, search query) are in that URL. I define it in the View Model and then use it. I wrote test code first which was not knockout and simply added the results to a list view and it worked.

Comment: I changed the call to  $.getJSON(self.foursquareURL, function(data). Now I see in the console.log that the data is received from the API. Only the first one get's added to the view. So I guess there is something wrong with the data binding in the view

Comment: Once  for loop is done are you able to see array of objects in venueList observableArray ? Avoid multiple declarations of venueList & remove declaration inside .getJson .

Comment: That was it, it was the double venueList inside .getJSON.

Comment: Cool! Will you guys please post the answer so it might help others, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments

Please make sure you declare the observable /observableArray once and re-use it . Avoid duplicates declarations as you have one such in getJSON .